# Change spectrum and normalization

Tags: frequency-spectrum, noise, ifft

I have a question about magnitude of a spectrum. My task is to build the spectrum and make IFFT - the result waveform should have unity amplitude.

For example:

1. Create 2 arrays with Magnitudes and Phases;
2. Fill the magnitudes array with noise (for example Perlin noise or white uniform noise);
3. Fill the phases with noise too;
4. Build the symmetrical-rectangular spectrum based on the above arrays (the first and FFTSize / 2 elements of imaginary arrays are zeroed too);
5. Perform IFFT;
6. The output waveform should contains the noise with unity amplitude.

I have troubles because on the output i have single impulse with unity amplitude and silent noise.

The code:

```
' Main code
 
Private Sub Form_Load()

    . . .

    InitSoundFromFile "C:\temp\test_spin.wav"

    DrawSpectrum picSpectrumOrigin, m_fSpectrum, m_cWavFile.SampleRate

    Randomize 1, 1  ' // Replace data with noise

    IFFT

    DrawSpectrum picSpectrumModified, m_fSpectrum, m_cWavFile.SampleRate
    DrawWaveform picWaveForm, m_fSamples, m_cWavFile.SampleRate

End Sub
 
' Noise/Signal ratio
 
Private Sub Randomize( _
            ByVal fMagnitude As Single, _
            ByVal fPhase As Single)
    Dim lIndex  As Long
    Dim fMag    As Single
    Dim fPh     As Single

    For lIndex = 0 To m_cFFT.FFTSize \ 2

        fMag = Rnd / (m_cFFT.FFTSize / 2)
        fPh = Rnd / (m_cFFT.FFTSize / 2)

        m_fSpectrum(0, lIndex) = fMag * fMagnitude + (1 - fMagnitude) * m_fSpectrum(0, lIndex)
        m_fSpectrum(1, lIndex) = fPh * fPhase + (1 - fPhase) * m_fSpectrum(1, lIndex)

    Next
 
End Sub
 
Private Sub IFFT()
    Dim fRectSpectrum() As Single
    Dim lIndex          As Long
    Dim lFFTSize        As Long

    lFFTSize = UBound(m_fSpectrum, 2) * 2

    ReDim fRectSpectrum(1, lFFTSize - 1)

    For lIndex = 0 To UBound(m_fSpectrum, 2)

        fRectSpectrum(0, lIndex) = Cos(m_fSpectrum(1, lIndex)) * m_fSpectrum(0, lIndex)
        fRectSpectrum(1, lIndex) = Sin(m_fSpectrum(1, lIndex)) * m_fSpectrum(0, lIndex)

    Next

    For lIndex = 1 To lFFTSize - 1
 
        fRectSpectrum(0, lFFTSize - lIndex) = fRectSpectrum(0, lIndex)
        fRectSpectrum(1, lFFTSize - lIndex) = -fRectSpectrum(1, lIndex)

    Next

    fRectSpectrum(1, 0) = 0
    fRectSpectrum(1, lFFTSize \ 2) = 0

    m_cFFT.IFFTR fRectSpectrum(), m_fSamples

    Debug.Print m_fSamples(0)

End Sub
```

**InitSoundFromFile** - just creates a waveform from a file (just container) and calculates the spectrum to *m_fSpectrum* array;
**Randomize** - adds the noise to *m_fSpectrum* array (with arguments equal to 1 it just replace signal with noise);

The output i have:

[image]

ADDED:

I've fixed the single impulse time-domain result by change range of phase-randomization from -PI to PI. I still can't calculate magnitude bins values to get the unity noise amplitude in time domain. What's the value of noise should i add in frequency domain to get unity noise value in time domain?

Now i add the random values from (0..1) / (FFTSize / 2) range to bins but then i get the time domain noise with 1.968998E-02 maximum amplitude after IFFT.

Comment: Can you add a plot of your result?

Comment: I've fixed problem with single pulse (just i've changed random-range for phases from -pi to pi), but i still can't calculate bins values to get unity time domain noise.

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of the FFT will likely scale by the number of samples N depending on the specific algorithm you use. So the IFFF will be 1/N. Just multiply your FFT bins by N to normalize it. If you use any windowing this will change the result accordingly

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. For example, i can set anyone bin magnitude to 0.5 (others set to zero) and the result time-domain waveform will contain sine with unity amplitude. If i set 0.25 to 2 any bins i get two sine with 0.5 amplitudes so the result time-domain waveform will contain the unity amplitude of two sines (0.5 + 0.5). How to add a noise? The noise has a random phase and amplitude. How to calculate bins in order to output amplitude has unity value?

Comment: I see - so if it is noise are you looking for the standard deviation to be normalized? Is your noise white?

Comment: Yes my noise is white, but i plan to add different ones like Perlin noise. I will describe my final task a little: I am writing a synthesizer of sounds in the frequency domain and I need noise as a starting point, which I will then change (smooth, threshold, release etc.) to reproduce final sound.